# TFIDF representation for ML dataset in coo format python

Tags: python, tf-idf

I would like to obtain the **tf-idf** representation for MovieLens tag dataset. The tags are in a 'coo' format:

```
import pandas as pd

ratings = pd.read_csv('data/ratings.csv',sep=',')
movies = pd.read_csv('data/movies.csv',sep=',')
tags = pd.read_csv('data/tags.csv',sep=',')
print(tags)

       userId  movieId                                      tag  \
0         15      339                            sandra 'boring' bullock   
1         15     1955                                            dentist   
2         15     7478                                           Cambodia   
3         15    32892                                            Russian   
4         15    34162                                        forgettable   
5         15    35957                                              short   
6         15    37729                                         dull story   
7         15    45950                                         powerpoint   
8         15   100365                                           activist   
9         15   100365                                        documentary   
10        15   100365                                             uganda   
11        23      150                                         Ron Howard 
...
```

The first version of my tf-idf code looks like this:

```
 vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(use_idf=True, norm= 'l2')
 X = vectorizer.fit_transform(tags['tag'])

 print(X)

 (0, 89)    0.603928505945
 (0, 80)    0.52013528953
 (0, 577)   0.603928505945
 (1, 160)   1.0
 (2, 94)    1.0
 (3, 573)   1.0
 (4, 255)   1.0
 (5, 604)   1.0
  ...
```

While this looks nice, it is not the exact representation that I want. There are two main problems:

1. I think each line in the 'tag' matrix is treated as one document which is not true. Many movies are tagged by different users added as separate entries.
2. The ids in 'X' are matrix indices. How can I know the corresponding ML-ids? Suppose I want to know the tf-idf representation for movie with MLid: 150. How can I know this?

It would be nice if you could let me know how I can fix the above cases which I think is quite an easy task.

Comment: what would you define as a document? The concatenation of all the tags by movies?

Comment: Each movie is a document. in this case, in the tag matrix, each document has a got a unique movieId. So, yes concatenation of all tags for a given movie define that document (movie).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Input**

```
userId  movieId tag
15  339 sandra 'boring' bullock
15  1955    dentist
15  7478    Cambodia
15  32892   Russian
15  34162   forgettable
15  35957   short
15  37729   dull story
15  45950   powerpoint
15  100365  activist
15  100365  documentary
15  100365  uganda
23  150 Ron Howard
```

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd

# consolidated dataset
tags = pd.read_csv('tfidf_input1.csv')
concatenated_tags = tags.groupby('movieId')['tag'].apply(lambda x: "%s" % ' '.join(x)).reset_index()
#print concatenated_tags

# TfidfVectorization
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
vec = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vec.fit_transform(concatenated_tags['tag'])
#print X

# knowing IDs in tftdf matrix
# you have to convert to dense [NOT AT ALL advised for large matrices]
# the output is a compressed sparse matrix for the memory reason
X_dense = X.todense()
print vec.get_feature_names()
print X_dense[0,:] # output for the first movieId
```

Comment: The answers looks like what I needed, thanks. One problem still remains which is as follows:   the output of `concatenated_tags` in your code returns to me a matrix of size `(689, 764)`. [`689` movies (documents), `764` tags (words)]. However, in reality the number of movies is `9125`. This means a lot of movies have not been tagged. Now, in your code how can I know the rows of `X` correspond to which `movieId`? Thanks

Comment: X_dense should return the right dimensions of the matrix... X is still a sparse compressed one...for retrieving by movie id, you need to get the index of that movieid from the original dataset...the corresponding index in X_dense should give you the correct vector!

Comment: Thank you very much Vivek. The answer was precise and solved my problem. I marked your response as the true answer.